# How can ddev automatically create additional databases?

Tags: ddev

This is a followup question to [How can I create and load a second database in ddev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785023/how-can-i-create-and-load-a-second-database-in-ddev/49785024). It is about doing that task *automatically*.

One use case for this is developing a migration to Drupal from another MySQL database, and collaborating with others on the migration. If the database name can be set by ddev, additional developers can get the database created automatically, and additional databases can be added to their settings.local.php, using known values.

Comment: It seems like a couple of mysql commands as post-start execs would work, but I haven't been able to get them to work yet. I've tried the form `- exec: "mysql --host=db --port=3306 --user=root --password=root -e \"IF NOT EXISTS testdb CREATE DATABASE testdb\""`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this in your project's config.yaml:

```
hooks:
  post-start:
    - exec: mysql -uroot -proot -hdb -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS another_db; GRANT ALL ON another_db.* TO 'db'@'%';"
```

Comment: Perfect! That works well, and doesn't get in the way on repeated starts. Thanks @rfay!