# How to pair DDEV databases for a migration from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, ddev

I realise this is not strictly speaking a ddev support question, but I am hoping you can point me in the right direction.

Quite simply, I want to upgrade a Drupal 7 site to Drupal 8 with the Migrate module. Both sites would be in their own DDEV containers. But how to get the their databases talking to each other?

Hoping this is not such a big ask.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you need two databases but one (d8) codebase for a migration like this. You could use the technique in [How can I create and load a second database in ddev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785023/how-can-i-create-and-load-a-second-database-in-ddev) to get your second database going.

For more detail and nuance on Drupal migrations, see @alexmoreno's [article on drupal migration with ddev](https://dev.acquia.com/article/migrating-drupal-6-drupal-8-boss)

Answer (score 1):

DDEV projects can communicate between each other, the key is in the host of the source database (in this case the Drupal 7 one).

Copy the database connection from the Drupal 10 ddev generated settings file, including the variables used and change the $host to "ddev-PROJECTNAME-db", where PROJECTNAME is the project that you wish to connect to.

Here's a video that shows how to set up the connection https://youtu.be/ok0T3l5tPYM.

Comment: Add relevant parts of the video to your answer. The video can become unreachable as time goes on and your answer would become useless for future readers.